# 'Rebuilding Library because the asset database could not be found!' error in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've created a repository from a GitHub template. When I tried to open the project, this log occured and I couldn't see any of the objects on the scene. How to solve it?

I tried to delete Library folder and open the project again from the Hub. The Library folder was created again, but the error also occured again.

Comment: Sounds like they didnt include any meta files. And its a duff github

Comment: is this an error or a warning? rebuilding the library isn't an issue at all but normal - the library contains only temporary generated data and is always recreated when opening the project the first time

Comment: It appears you are experiencing an issue with Unity after importing a project from a GitHub template. To better assist you, could you please provide more details? Specifically, what is the Unity version you are using, what is the nature of the GitHub template (e.g., a complete Unity project, an asset package, etc.), were there any issues or particular steps you took while importing the project, and could you share the exact error message you are receiving? This information can help others diagnose your problem more effectively.